# babel-loader'у нужен WebPack? Зачем?

Tags: node.js, npm

Привет. Только что закончил миграцию своего проекта на другой сервер и последнее, что нужно было сделать - установить npm и зависимости проекта. После того, как всё успешно установилось, появился warning:

> npm WARN babel-loader@7.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@2 || 3 but none
>   was installed.

Зачем это ещё babel-лоадеру WebPack? Он будет работать без WebPack?

Comment: Может я что-то не понял, но для webpack'а нужно сделать интерфейс, без которого он знать не знает о babel'е и любых других вещах типа stylus. Модульность же.

Comment: @Aid да, вы не совсем поняли вопрос. Я использую Gulp для сборки, но мне нужно один файлик пройтись babel-лоадером и собрать его с пресетом es2015. Вот у меня и возникает вопрос, при чём тут вообще WebPack?

Comment: А при том: `babel-loader` - это загрузчик для Webpack. [Пруф](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader). Для того, чтобы подружить Gulp и Babel, нужен https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel

Comment: @Aid то есть, в моём случае мне вообще не нужен `babel-loader` и `.babelrc`?

Comment: Почитайте что документацию, чтобы понять как вообще это работает. `babel-loader` Вам не нужен, раз у Вас `Gulp`, а вот `.babelrc` - нужен, это настройки для babel.

Comment: @Aid спасибо. Оформите ответом, пожалуйста. Похоже, что я посмотрел немного не тот скринкаст :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`babel-loader`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) - это загрузчик для Webpack.
Для того, чтобы подружить Gulp и Babel, нужен [`gulp-babel`](http://github.com/babel/gulp-babel)